# Android HTTPPost Null

Tags: php, android, http-post

I am trying to post a string to a php file on my web server from my android phone. I am able to establish a connection to the file, as I can retrieve what it prints. The problem I am having is sending the POST variable, which continually seems to be null(I am testing the program now, and sending back what the POST variable is). Here is the relevant code:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(HTTP://WWW....PHP FILE ADDRESS);
    try{
                // the data to send
                 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RoomName", "HELLO"));//params[1]
                // http post
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 InputStream is = entity.getContent();
```

My PHP code is (at the moment) as follows:

```
  $roomname = $_POST['RoomName'];
  $returnArray[] = array("LoggedIn" => $roomname);
  print_r(json_encode($returnArray));
```

I have been looking at forums for the past week, and all the httppost examples follow this almost exactly. I would appreciate any help that you are willing to give. Thanks a lot

Comment: if you need any of my other code for a better idea of what I am trying to do please let me know

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, stopped working on the project and forgot about it. I believe I used a GET request instead

Answer (score 0):

Well, try $_REQUEST in place $_POST.